# Using StratifiedShuffleSplit with sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to replicate the example of [`StratifiedShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) with X not being an array but a sparse matrix. In the example below, this matrix was created by a `DictVectorizer` fit to an array of mixed nominal and numerical features.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit

X = [{"a":1, "b":"xx"}, {"a":2, "b":"yx"}, {"a":2, "b":"yx"}, {"a":1, "b":"xx"}]
y = ["A", "B", "B", "A"]

X = DictVectorizer().fit_transform(X)
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, 3, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in sss:
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

When I run the script, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 22, in <module>
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

This is because X is not an array but a sparse matrix. So the question is, how can I split the data using this method when X is not an array but a matrix? Perhaps the problem is not scikit-learn specifically, but numpy? Do I have to "transform" **train_index** and **test_index** before "applying" them to X? Or maybe I have to "tranform" **X** instead?

According to the documentation of **StratifiedShuffleSplit**, for it to work with matrices, I should pass **True** to the parameter **indices**, but it doesn't help.

Any suggestion you could give me would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that in your version of scikit-learn `DictVectorizer` returns COO matrix that is not row-wise indexable (the scipy error message is not very explicit unfortunately). To fix the issue convert the vectorized ouput to CSR format by replacing the line:

```
X = DictVectorizer().fit_transform(X)
```

by

```
X = DictVectorizer().fit_transform(X).tocsr()
```

Comment: Also note: on scikit-learn master, DictVectorizer now returns a CSR by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass `indices=True` to `StratifiedShuffleSplit` as specified [in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit).

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to split and shuffle a sparse matrix in python, mybe that helps:

```
def splitSparseMatrix(matrix):
    trainingSet =  matrix[:trainingSetSize,:]
    testSet = matrix[-testSetSize:,:]
    return trainingSet, testSet

def shuffleSparseMatrix(smatrix):
    indexList = np.arange(np.shape(matrix)[0])
    np.random.shuffle(indexList)
    return matrix[indexList, :]
```